# how to avoid multiple call from mouse up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function on `mouseup`. when user click and select some text in document and click the save button i need to save that text.

when user click and not save a button (whatever times), my function is keep calling after the user click on save text button.

how to avoid this?

here is my js:

```
$('.documentpage').mouseup(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($.trim(window.getSelection().toString()).length) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            //delaying to get selection
            if (rangy.supported && classApplierModule && classApplierModule.supported) {
                boldRedApplier = rangy.createCssClassApplier('');
                currentSelection = boldRedApplier.validateSelection();

                valid = that.isValidText(currentSelection);

                if (!valid) {
                    currentSelection.contents().unwrap();
                    that.clearTextSelection();
                    return;
                }

                if (valid.status) {
                    that.saveTextButton.show();
                    that.saveTextButton.click(function () {
                        that.onValidSelection(currentSelection); //it calls multiple tiems, whatver the user selected on valid.
                    })

                }

            }
        }, 100);
    }
});
```

Comment: Try using clearTimeout() after calling your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems to be with trying to add an event listener inside your function every time there is a `mouseup` event. Try setting up `that.saveTextButton.click(function ()` separately and just showing the button on `mouseup`. I had to fiddle with it a little not having all the vars your code needs but you should get the idea:

```js
var valid =true;
//var valid =false;

$('.documentpage').mouseup(function(e){
                e.stopPropagation();
                if($.trim(window.getSelection().toString()).length) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                    //delaying to get selection
                      
                      //..other code that checks stuff...
                      
                      if(valid){ 
                           $('#saveTextButton').show();

                      }                      
                    }, 100);
                } 
});


$('#saveTextButton').click(function(){
  
      alert('function called');
  
});
```

```css
.documentpage{
 height:100px;
  width:1000px;
  background-color:#cccccc;
  }

#saveTextButton{
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="documentpage">this is some test text</div>
<input type="button" id="saveTextButton" value="Push me"></input>
```

Comment: I removed the setTimeout completly still i am facing issue.

Comment: here is the issue, `that.saveTextButton.click(function () {
        that.onValidSelection(currentSelection);
        clearTimeout(timeout);
       })` each time i mouseup simply it adds the listener how to avoid it?

Comment: add your listener as a separate function. In this function just set the button to visible

Comment: I tried this way `if(valid.status){
       that.saveTextButton.show();
       return function () {
        that.saveTextButton.click(function () {
        that.onValidSelection(currentSelection);
        })
       }();
       
      } ` but not working